# Jmeter - Break a loop once the condition is met

Tags: jmeter

In my thread I get `active_status` parameter from Cassandra DataBase.  I need to run on each active_status var been created from Cassandra sample (active_status_1, active_status_2, etc..) and check if it's `active`.

When not active it should skip and do nothing and if it's `active` I need to do an action only once and then stop (so even if I have 10 `active` results, it will perform the action ("report" in my case) only on the first one).

[image: Thread flow]

active_status vars from debug response

[image: inactive vars]

media_id vars from debug response

[image: media_id]

http request where I use the counter

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

My action (report) request is: `story_id=evE0-001-085121182-5&media_id=1021372295263777595_175887011&who=admin&reason=offensive&blogger_id=Amit` even though "1021372295263777595_175887011" is not ACTIVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

- [User Parameters PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) once as a child of a Sampler before the ForEach Controller to init RUN_ONCE to false:

[image]

and once as a child of the HTTP Request that runs on active status to set RUN_ONCE to true
[image]

- [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) with following settings[image]:
- [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)  and put in condition:

> ${__jexl2( "${status}" == "ACTIVE" && "${RUN_ONCE}" == "false")}

[image]
- Test Plan would look like this:

[image]

You counter should be in ForEachController not in If Controller as it will not increment correctly and give the ID for the correct status

Comment: Where should I put the counter?
I've tried this code in While: ${__jexl2( "${active_status${counter}}" == "ACTIVE" && "${counter}" < 1 )}.
and put the counter under the while controller (starts with "0" and increments by 1). 
But it's not getting inside the while..

Comment: I managed to solve this one. The problem was with the quotes on "counter" var. So it's getting into the while controller but stops only after "counter" 1, even though the first two "active_status" are not active so it should continue to the next one

Comment: But in that case, won't it just run on all "active_status"? If if get it right, with this option, it will run on all "active_status_(number)" and make the report action on all of them which are active. I don't need to report more than once.
So to explain again:
Run on active_status_1 -> if active -> report and stop the loop. Only if not active -> skip to active_status_2 -> if active - > report and stop

Comment: I updated my post with screenshot trying your solution.
The action (report) is done on a media which is not active .(INACTIVE_FORCED_ADMIN in this case).

Comment: Added requested screenshots

Comment: I added If Controller screenshot, although it should work for you, I simulate exactly what you show and I got the expected behaviour, where in your plan do you extract active_status and media_id, your issue might be in your counter if you send wrong media_id

Comment: Added Cassandra sampler screenshot where I extract the active_status and media_id vars. 
I started the counter with 1 and increased by 1

Comment: Worked! Didn't see where you said to move the counter on previous comments. Now it's under Foreach and works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'while controller' with a condition:

`${__javaScript( "${some_var}" = "something" && "${some_other_var}" < "${something_else}"; )}`

One of those expressions should refer to counter, another to status.